# How to improve performance of SQL Server stored procedure that is building INSERT statements

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am currently working on a conversion where I need to convert data coming out of a Cobol system into SQL Server. We are using SSIS to parse the extract into temporary tables. Then we use stored procedures to build files that can be validated and imported into the new system. I am currently stuck on the requirements for how I must process the sample data below.

The sample data in this post provides the data necessary for generating bill history in our new system. The fields R_PS28_STRT_DT_1 and R_PS28_STRT_DT_2 indicate the date of the first bill in that schedule. And, R_PS28_NO_PMT_1 and R_PS28_NO_PMT_2 indicate how many billing history rows to insert into our billing history table for a given loan.

For example, based on the sample data provided, the first row would result in 24 `INSERT` statements with bill dates as follows. I know that I can open a cursor and process each schedule with a loop inside of the stored procedure. But, that makes me worry about performance since the production tables will be huge. Is there a better way of solving this outside of cursors and loops?

```
5/29/2015
6/29/2015
7/29/2015
8/29/2015
9/29/2015
10/29/2015
11/29/2015
12/29/2015
1/29/2016
2/29/2016
3/29/2016
4/29/2016
5/29/2016
6/29/2016
7/29/2016
8/29/2016
9/29/2016
10/29/2016
11/29/2016
12/29/2016
1/29/2017
2/29/2017
3/29/2017
4/29/2017


R_KEY               R_DUE_DTE_P R_PAST_DTE    R_PAYMENT  R_PS28_STRT_DT_1   R_PS28_NO_PMT_1 R_PS28_AMT_1    R_PS28_STRT_DT_2  R_PS28_NO_PMT_2   R_PS28_AMT_2    
47200161755171001   2016-10-29  2016-05-29    349.94     2016-05-29         12              349.94          2015-05-29        12                 0.00 
47200161755251001   2016-10-20  2016-05-20    166.92     2016-05-20         12              166.92          2015-05-20        12                0.00
47200161755331001   2016-10-21  2016-05-21    337.78     2016-05-21         12              337.78          2015-05-21        12                0.00
47200161755411001   2016-11-04  2016-06-04    194.66     2016-06-04         12              194.66          2015-06-04        12                0.00
47200161755581001   2016-10-21  2016-05-21    225.99     2016-05-21         12              225.99          2015-05-21        12                0.00
```

Below is my first pass at implementing a stored procedure to solve the problem described above.  It does work but, I'm not sure how it will perform on large data sets or if it is the optimal solution.  I'm open to any suggestions.  I'm mostly just looking for design ideas on better ways to solve the problem.  I know that I can write another procedure to get rid of the redundant WHILE loops.  I just haven't gotten around to that yet.

```
/* Table-Value Function that generates Billing History rows.  There are up
*  to 8 schedules that require billing history to be generated.  
*/

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[BuildBillingHistoryForLoan](@startDate1   datetime,
                                           @numPayments1 int,
                                           @pmtAmount1   money,
                                           @freq1        int,
                                           @startDate2   datetime,
                                           @numPayments2 int,
                                           @pmtAmount2   money,
                                           @freq2        int,
                                           @startDate3   datetime,
                                           @numPayments3 int,
                                           @pmtAmount3   money,
                                           @freq3        int,
                                           @startDate4   datetime,
                                           @numPayments4 int,
                                           @pmtAmount4   money,
                                           @freq4        int,
                                           @startDate5   datetime,
                                           @numPayments5 int,
                                           @pmtAmount5   money,
                                           @freq5        int,
                                           @startDate6   datetime,
                                           @numPayments6 int,
                                           @pmtAmount6   money,
                                           @freq6        int,
                                           @startDate7   datetime,
                                           @numPayments7 int,
                                           @pmtAmount7   money,
                                           @freq7        int,
                                           @startDate8   datetime,
                                           @numPayments8 int,
                                           @pmtAmount8   money,
                                           @freq8        int,
                                           @pastDueDate  datetime,
                                           @loanNumber varchar(30))
RETURNS @billingHistory TABLE (
    LoanNumber varchar(30),
    DueDate datetime,
    PaymentAmount money
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @counter INT

    DECLARE @currentBillDate datetime

    -- Schedule 1
    SET @currentBillDate = @startDate1  
    SET @counter = 0
    WHILE @currentBillDate is not null and @currentBillDate <> '1753-01-01' and @currentBillDate < @pastDueDate and @counter < @numPayments1
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO @billingHistory values (@loanNumber, @currentBillDate, @pmtAmount1)

        SET @counter = @counter + 1
        SET @currentBillDate = dbo.CalculateNextPayment(@currentBillDate, @freq1)
    END

    -- Schedule 2
    SET @currentBillDate = @startDate2  
    SET @counter = 0
    WHILE @currentBillDate is not null and @currentBillDate <> '1753-01-01' and @currentBillDate < @pastDueDate and @counter < @numPayments2
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO @billingHistory values (@loanNumber,@currentBillDate, @pmtAmount2)

        SET @counter = @counter + 1
        SET @currentBillDate = dbo.CalculateNextPayment(@currentBillDate, @freq2)
    END

    -- Schedule 3
    SET @currentBillDate = @startDate3
    SET @counter = 0
    WHILE @currentBillDate is not null and @currentBillDate <> '1753-01-01' and @currentBillDate < @pastDueDate and @counter < @numPayments3
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO @billingHistory values (@loanNumber, @currentBillDate, @pmtAmount3)

        SET @counter = @counter + 1
        SET @currentBillDate = dbo.CalculateNextPayment(@currentBillDate, @freq3)
    END

    -- Schedule 4
    SET @currentBillDate = @startDate4  
    SET @counter = 0
    WHILE @currentBillDate is not null and @currentBillDate <> '1753-01-01' and @currentBillDate < @pastDueDate and @counter < @numPayments4
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO @billingHistory values (@loanNumber, @currentBillDate, @pmtAmount4)

        SET @counter = @counter + 1
        SET @currentBillDate = dbo.CalculateNextPayment(@currentBillDate, @freq4)
    END

    -- Schedule 5
    SET @currentBillDate = @startDate5  
    SET @counter = 0
    WHILE @currentBillDate is not null and @currentBillDate <> '1753-01-01' and @currentBillDate < @pastDueDate and @counter < @numPayments5
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO @billingHistory values (@loanNumber, @currentBillDate, @pmtAmount5)

        SET @counter = @counter + 1
        SET @currentBillDate = dbo.CalculateNextPayment(@currentBillDate, @freq5)
    END

    -- Schedule 6
    SET @currentBillDate = @startDate6
    SET @counter = 0
    WHILE @currentBillDate is not null and @currentBillDate <> '1753-01-01' and @currentBillDate < @pastDueDate and @counter < @numPayments6
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO @billingHistory values (@loanNumber, @currentBillDate, @pmtAmount6)

        SET @counter = @counter + 1
        SET @currentBillDate = dbo.CalculateNextPayment(@currentBillDate, @freq6)
    END

    -- Schedule 7
    SET @currentBillDate = @startDate7
    SET @counter = 0
    WHILE @currentBillDate is not null and @currentBillDate <> '1753-01-01' and @currentBillDate < @pastDueDate and @counter < @numPayments7
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO @billingHistory values (@loanNumber, @currentBillDate, @pmtAmount7)

        SET @counter = @counter + 1
        SET @currentBillDate = dbo.CalculateNextPayment(@currentBillDate, @freq7)
    END

    -- Schedule 8
    SET @currentBillDate = @startDate8
    SET @counter = 0
    WHILE @currentBillDate is not null and @currentBillDate <> '1753-01-01' and @currentBillDate < @pastDueDate and @counter < @numPayments8
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO @billingHistory values (@loanNumber, @currentBillDate, @pmtAmount8)

        SET @counter = @counter + 1
        SET @currentBillDate = dbo.CalculateNextPayment(@currentBillDate, @freq8)
    END

    RETURN;
END;

/* INSERT Statement that tests the table-valued function to ensure that the
*  correct number of rows are inserted for each row in the loan table.
*/
INSERT INTO temp_bh
select LoanNumber, DueDate, PaymentAmount
FROM RFELOAN1 Loan1
INNER JOIN RFELOAN3 Loan3 on Loan3.r_key = Loan1.r_key
CROSS APPLY dbo.BuildBillingHistoryForLoan(Loan3.R_PS28_STRT_DT_1,Loan3.R_PS28_NO_PMT_1,Loan3.R_PS28_AMT_1,Loan3.R_PS28_SCHED_1, -- Schedule 1
                                           Loan3.R_PS28_STRT_DT_2,Loan3.R_PS28_NO_PMT_2,Loan3.R_PS28_AMT_2,Loan3.R_PS28_SCHED_2, -- Schedule 2
                                           Loan3.R_PS28_STRT_DT_3,Loan3.R_PS28_NO_PMT_3,Loan3.R_PS28_AMT_3,Loan3.R_PS28_SCHED_3, -- Schedule 3
                                           Loan3.R_PS28_STRT_DT_4,Loan3.R_PS28_NO_PMT_4,Loan3.R_PS28_AMT_4,Loan3.R_PS28_SCHED_4, -- Schedule 4
                                           Loan3.R_PS28_STRT_DT_5,Loan3.R_PS28_NO_PMT_5,Loan3.R_PS28_AMT_5,Loan3.R_PS28_SCHED_5, -- Schedule 5
                                           Loan3.R_PS28_STRT_DT_6,Loan3.R_PS28_NO_PMT_6,Loan3.R_PS28_AMT_6,Loan3.R_PS28_SCHED_6, -- Schedule 6
                                           Loan3.R_PS28_STRT_DT_7,Loan3.R_PS28_NO_PMT_7,Loan3.R_PS28_AMT_7,Loan3.R_PS28_SCHED_7, -- Schedule 7
                                           Loan3.R_PS28_STRT_DT_8,Loan3.R_PS28_NO_PMT_8,Loan3.R_PS28_AMT_8,Loan3.R_PS28_SCHED_8, -- Schedule 8
                                           Loan1.R_PAST_DTE, Loan3.R_KEY) -- Past Due Date
WHERE Loan1.R_KEY = Loan3.R_KEY AND R_CLOS = 0 AND
           ((R_TYPE_X = '3' AND R_MODE_X = '3') OR (R_TYPE_X = '6' AND R_MODE_X = '2'))
           -- R_TYPE_X (3 = Simple Int Amortization, 6 = Rule of 78s Amortization)
           -- R_MODE_X (3 = Principal and Interest with BH
```

Comment: Expected output?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense to me. Why is the first row going to generate 24 insert statements? You say that two columns are used to indicate the number of rows but the values of those two columns are 60 and 5. You are going to have to explain this more clearly.

Comment: My bad.  I simplified the data in the example locally and forgot to replace it in the post.  I fixed the sample result set.

Comment: That still doesn't really help. Do you take the sum of those two columns? And what exactly are you trying to do? I assume you want to insert some data into a table somewhere using some of this information as the source? I am guessing you would want to use a tally table here for your inserts but we have no idea what you are really trying to accomplish.

Comment: Basically, the stored procedure would look at the field R_PS28_STRT_DT_1 and R_PS28_NO_PMT_1.  R_PS28_NO_PMT_1 indicates how many billing history rows to insert.  R_PS28_STRT_DT_1 indicates the first bill due date.  Each subsequent billing history row has a bill due date of one month greater than the month prior.  The procedure would do the same for R_PS28_STRT_DT_2 and R_PS28_NO_PMT_2.

Comment: That's nice. I assume you want some help writing this query? I can't see your screen and have no idea what your base table or the target table structures are which means nobody can really help much. The answer by Mikhail Lobanov below seems like a great approach to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create table-valued function to to return billing history for each record.

Then `cross apply` or `outer apply` this function to your imported data. Result will be a full billing history for all data you imported in 1 `select`.
Now you can insert data with single `insert` statement

Something like this

```
INSERT INTO dbo.BillingHistory
SELECT ...
FROM sample_data_you_posted SD
CROSS APPLY dbo.fn_BillingHistory(SD.R_PS28_STRT_DT_1, SD.R_PS28_STRT_DT_2, SD.R_PS28_NO_PMT_1, SD.R_PS28_NO_PMT_2)
```

Comment: Thanks, that definitely gives me a a better approach.  So, would the fn_BillingHistory function create a temp table with the billing history for each loan?

Comment: It depends on realization. In case of inline function there are no buffers, if your function is not inline buffer for output will be created